What are the steps create a virtual machine in Google colab?
Simple question : they’re lot of tutorials in how to use a vm on google colab. Or how to add a gpu to an existing vm.
But how do I create a vm in the first place in order to get shell access ? I’m failing to find where I should click on the landing page
I’m meaning what are the steps by step menu ?

This [so] post may be of interest How can I run shell (terminal) in Google Colab?

Google Colaboratory automatically create a private virtual machine for each account, install on it the Jupyter Notebook app required software and do the default setup and connections to the required Google services, like Google Drive.
To create your own virtual machine you have to use another service, then install and setup the software and services required to run a Jupyter Notebook application. Please ber mind that if you want to use Google Drive to store the Jupyter Notebook content files you will have to setup the connection.
One option is to use the Google Cloud Platform. For details, see
Instructions for starting a GCE VM on Colab via GCP Marketplace

For your convenience, below there is a couple of Q/A that mentinons "virtual machine", taken from https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

Where is my code executed? What happens to my execution state if I close the browser window?
Code is executed in a virtual machine private to your account. Virtual machines are deleted when idle for a while, and have a maximum lifetime enforced by the Colab service.


How can I reset the virtual machine(s) my code runs on, and why is this sometimes unavailable?
Selecting Runtime > Disconnect and delete runtime to return all managed virtual machines assigned to you to their original state. This can be helpful in cases where a virtual machine has become unhealthy e.g. due to accidental overwrite of system files, or installation of incompatible software. Colab limits how often this can be done to prevent undue resource consumption. If an attempt fails, please try again later.


This is good for running a code snippet. But not to run a binary you compile on the machine… I need a ᴠᴍ with a shell, not an app engine instance.

@user2284570 The question was how to create a VM. If you want to know how to use the Shell in Google Colaboratory ask that in a new question.
